# CSS + <img> webkit's implementation with using %

Tags: css, webkit, image

Seems to be quite different in **webkit** compared to ie/ff/opera.

To replicate - take an image that is like say, w: 200px h: 400px.

drop in **html** like this.

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="whattheeff" src="/image.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="render bug" />
</div>
```

and add **css** like

```
<style>
div#container{height:1000px;background:#fff;border:1px dashed #000;}
img#whattheeff{width:200px; height:100%;}
</style>
```

The result is most browsers displaying the image at it's original height 400px and webkit showing the image at the height of its parent. 1000px.

Anyone seen this before? anyone have a suggestion for getting webkit to play the same.

Comment: The img is a block-level, replaced element in normal flow.  FWICS in http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property the webkit behaviour is correct, the height is relative to the containing block.

Comment: @p00ya - <img> is an inline element.

Comment: oops, so it is.  However, section 10.6.2 (Inline replaced elements, block-level replaced elements in normal flow, 'inline-block' replaced elements in normal flow and floating replaced elements) still applies: the height is relative to the containing block.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem:

I set `height:auto;` instead of `100%`.

Turns out `auto` ignores the declaration in the image tag and looks at the `auto` height of the image...the same as 100% does in most browsers except webkit.

Lessoned learned. Thanks to Cork on #jquery on freenode.

Answer (score 0):

Actually firefox/ie(8) and chrome(webkit) renders image with parents height.